# filtering out rows of data using dates within each row using R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, filtering

Representative dataset:

```
ID,drug_start,date_of_bloods,result
1234,NA,12-10-2010,80
1234,NA,12-10-2011,50
1234,NA,12-10-2013,10
4532,05-03-2015,01-01-2013,80
4532,05-03-2015,01-01-2014,60
4532,05-03-2015,01-01-2016,40
7894,04-09-2016,03-08-2012,40
7894,04-09-2016,03-08-2014,38
7894,04-09-2016,02-06-2015,30
7894,04-09-2016,29-10-2016,27
7894,04-09-2016,10-10-2017,26
```

I would like to filter this to result >20 and those rows where the date_of_bloods is < drug_start within each row. Where NA is in the drug_start column I would like them just filtered on result >20. Desired outcome would be:

```
ID,drug_start,date_of_bloods,result
1234,NA,12-10-2010,80
1234,NA,12-10-2011,50
4532,05-03-2015,01-01-2013,80
4532,05-03-2015,01-01-2014,60
7894,04-09-2016,03-08-2012,40
7894,04-09-2016,03-08-2014,38
7894,04-09-2016,02-06-2015,30
```

So far I have tried :

```
table <- readxl::read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet = "bloods")
table <- as.data.frame(table)
table$result <- as.numeric(table$result)
table<- subset(table, result >20)
table$date_of_bloods <- as.Date(table$date_of_bloods, format="%d/%m/%Y")
table$drug_start <- as.Date(table$drug_start, format="%d/%m/%Y")
table[!(table$drug_start >= table$date_of_bloods),]
```

The final line does not work and just turns all the rows where drug_start is NA to all columns reading NA and the dates not having filtered.

Your help would be greatly welcomed

Comment: Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s). Use `dput()` for data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the dates to actual and date and use `subset` to select rows where `result` is greater than 20 and `date_of_bloods < drug_start` or `drug_start` is `NA`.

```
table$date_of_bloods <- as.Date(table$date_of_bloods, format="%d-%m-%Y")
table$drug_start <- as.Date(table$drug_start, format="%d-%m-%Y")

subset(table, result > 20 & (date_of_bloods < drug_start | is.na(drug_start)))

#    ID drug_start date_of_bloods result
#1 1234       <NA>     2010-10-12     80
#2 1234       <NA>     2011-10-12     50
#4 4532 2015-03-05     2013-01-01     80
#5 4532 2015-03-05     2014-01-01     60
#7 7894 2016-09-04     2012-08-03     40
#8 7894 2016-09-04     2014-08-03     38
#9 7894 2016-09-04     2015-06-02     30
```

The same logic using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

table %>%
  mutate(across(c(drug_start, date_of_bloods), lubridate::dmy)) %>%
  filter(result > 20 & (date_of_bloods < drug_start | is.na(drug_start)))
```

Comment: thanks Ronak that worked perfectly. To clarify for my understanding when I was using as.Date in my attempt I should have been using '-' instead of '/'? Further to that my filtering didn't work as I was wasn't using subset?

Comment: In `format` of `as.Date` you should specify what format you have. In your data you have format `"%d-%m-%Y"` with "-" bu you specified `%d/%m/%Y"` with `"/"` which turned all the dates to `NA` and so your next line did not work since all the dates were `NA`.

Comment: Thank you again for taking the time to help, makes perfect sense! Out of interest would table[!(table$drug_start >= table$date_of_bloods),] then work if dates had been formatted properly?

Comment: Yes, it would but then it would not select the first 2 `NA` rows for that you need to add another condition as mentioned in my answer using `is.na`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!